# Is finding the tangent plane to a surface made any more complicated if the surface $\neq 0$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

So I have $x^2 + y^2 - z^2 = 4$ as my surface and the point I'm looking at is $(2,1,1)$.

So if it was $0$, I'd do my partial derivatives and get the equation:

$4(x - 2 ) + 2(y-1) - 2(z-1) = 0 $

right? And that's my equation. Apparently that's worth 7 marks but it certainly doesn't seem like it. If it's not 0, but 4, is my answer not just

$4(x - 2 ) + 2(y-1) - 2(z-1) = 4 $ ?

I'm essentially trying to teach myself multivariable calculus in 2 weeks so I apologize for seeming slow.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the value of the function has no effect on the level surface or the tangent plane.

Suppose that $F$ is your function, and $F(2, 1, 1) = 4$. If I define

$$
G(x, y, z) = F(x, y, z) -4
$$
then the surface defined by $G = 0$ is the same as the one defined by $F = 4$. Since $G$ and $F$ have the same derivative, the tangent plane that you compute using the derivative will be exactly the same in the two cases (which is good, because the two surfaces are identical!).

Comment: So to answer the question: find the tangent plane to the surface:

 $x^2 + y^2 - z^2 = 4$ 

my answer of $ 4(x−2)+2(y−1)−2(z−1)= 0$
 is right?

  Would I be expected to expand this?

Comment: Your answer is indeed correct. *Someone* might say "no, you have to write $4x + 2y - 2z -8 = 0$ (i.e., have to expand it out and collect terms), but since your answer is in one of the standard forms for a plane equation ("point-normal form"), I'm completely happy with it.

Let me add one more thing: a pitch for precision in mathematical expression. Your question is not about the *surface* being zero or nonzero, but about some function. Better would be "Is the formula for the tangent plane to an implicitly-defined surface any different for $F(x, y, z) = c$ than for $F(x, y, z) = 0$?"